# ${HTTPD-...} Perl syntax

Tags: bash, shell

Ok, I can't figure this out from reading Perl's documentation. I'm looking at the RHEL4 init script for Apache... What does this line of code do?

```
httpd=${HTTPD-/usr/sbin/httpd}
```

Why not just `httpd=/usr/sbin/httpd`? What's up with all the extra syntax?

-Geoffrey Lee

Comment: That's not Perl, looks like shell.

Comment: That would explain why the Perl docs didn't help! :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not Perl, its shell.  Init scripts are usually written in shell.  Specifically it means "if defined, use the HTTPD environment variable, otherwise use /usr/sbin/httpd".

Look [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/bashref/ShellParameterExpansion.html) for more info.

Comment: do you think OP has a typo error? should it be $HTTPD:- instead of just -

Comment: `${VAR-default}` works, though its not the documented bash way to do it.  I can't say more, I'm not much of a shell programmer.

Comment: It certainly is documented:  look for the section "Paramater Expansion" in the man page.

Comment: @glenn I did.  I even linked to it.  Look closely, the documented version is `${VAR:-default}` where the OP is using `${VAR-default}`.  Note the lack of a colon.  Maybe somewhere its documented that the colon is optional, but its not immediately obvious from the docs.

Comment: @Schwern: It's documented in the man page in the sentence immediately preceding the section about `${VAR:-default}` as you can see in my answer. "Omitting the colon..." It's worded a little differently in the reference you linked to, but it's in the same place. It **is** easy to miss (I did for a long time).

Comment: @Dennis Yep. I missed it because I was searching for `:` and skimming the list of parameter styles.

Answer (score 2):

The colon affects whether the variable is checked for being unset or null versus only checking for whether it's unset.

```
$ var="goodbye"; echo ${var-hello}
goodbye
$ var="goodbye"; echo ${var:-hello}
goodbye
$ var= ; echo ${var:-hello}
hello
$ var= ; echo ${var-hello}    # var is null, only test for unset so no sub. made

$ unset var; echo ${var:-hello}
hello
$ unset var; echo ${var-hello}
hello
```

From the Bash man page:

```
       When not performing substring expansion,  using  the  forms  documented
       below,  bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null.  Omitting the
       colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.

       ${parameter:-word}
              Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null,  the  expan‐
              sion  of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter
              is substituted.
```